# set taxonomy without removing existing

Tags: php, wordpress

```
wp_set_object_terms( $update_id, $_POST['add_categories'], 'listing-category' );
```

I am using this function to set taxonomy from front-end . Its working fine but clear all existing taxonomy and set this taxonomy. I want to set taxonomy without removing existing. Any Help?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

From [Doc](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_post_terms)

```
<?php wp_set_post_terms( $post_id, $terms, $taxonomy, $append ) ?>
```

**$append**
    (boolean) (optional) *If true, tags will be appended to the post. If false, tags will replace existing tags*. Default: false

Comment: wp_set_object_terms( $update_id, $_POST['add_categories'], 'listing-category', true );  this worked for me